# Get values set in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this kind of table, on an SQLite database :

[image]

Is there a way to get all the different values for the username column, ie getting - in this example - user1 user2 user3 without others informations ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both queries would yield the same result:

```
SELECT
  username
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY username
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  username
FROM
  mytable
```

The difference is that you can add some aggregate functions to your username `group` like `count(*)` to see how many times a particular `username` appears in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Try using distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username
FROM mytable
```